# Create a dictionary out of an array in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary out of an array and assign a new custom object to each of them. I'll do stuff with the objects later. How can I do this?

```
var cals = [1,2,3] 
// I want to create out of this the following dictionary
// [1:ReminderList() object, 2:ReminderList() object, 3:ReminderList() object]

let calendarsHashedToReminders = cals.map { ($0, ReminderList()) } // Creating a tuple works!

let calendarsHashedToReminders = cals.map { $0: ReminderList() } // ERROR: "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"
```

Comment: put them in the brackets , cals.map { [$0: ReminderList()] }

Comment: Do you want a dictionary or an array of dictionaries? Because that's what ogres and Sahil Kapoor is suggesting.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. I'd like to have one dictionary not an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map()` returns an `Array` so you'll either have to use `reduce()` or create the dictionary like this:

```
var calendars: [Int: ReminderList] = [:]
cals.forEach { calendars[$0] = ReminderList() }
```

You can also use `reduce()` to get a oneliner but I'm not a fan of using `reduce()` to create an Array or a Dictionary.

Comment: You'll need `var calendars...` since it's being mutated

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I always make that mistake. :)